# Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal() error in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am facing this issue while building `flutter` apps in `VS Code` and I could not find any simple solution for this issue. Please help me resolve this issue.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

> Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
> Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (/home/jatin/.gradle/caches/journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
> Owner PID: 3813
> Our PID: 5034
> Owner Operation:
> Our operation:
> Lock file: /home/jatin/.gradle/caches/journal-1/journal-1.lock
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 1m 2s
> Running Gradle task ‘assembleDebug’…
> Running Gradle task ‘assembleDebug’… Done 63.5s
> Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

A detailed solution would be appreciated.
Also, I am unaware of the `stacktrace` option .(* Try:
Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Had the same problem, these actions worked for me:
Close IDE.
Go to windows task manager -> processes.
Find java.exe processes there and end them.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I always just use `killall java` for linux

Answer (score 21):

That Gradle failure message would be:

```
Gradle sync failed: Timeout waiting to lock daemon addresses registry [...].
It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

Owner PID: 4567
Our PID: 5678
Owner Operation: ...
```

If you're using macOS or linux for development, just kill the owner process:

```
sudo kill -9 4567
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem but thankfully I found a way to do it without restarting the container.
Ran the following command to stop daemons on Gradle. This made the other daemon stop and blocking my Gradle runs

```
./gradlew --stop
```

OR

```
gradle --stop
```

Comment: Do it inside the android folder. It works.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when interrupting a batch file that was calling individual groovy scripts like

```
os.system('./gradlew chromeTest --tests=\"MyTestScript_1\")
```

The batch file contains several calls like the one above, and I interrupted it due to errors in my scripts. Once the errors were corrected, I tried again to run the batch file but then I got the error reported in this ticket.

To solve it I tried to stop gradle with

> ./gradlew --stop

or

> gradle --stop

and then restarting gradle with

> ./gradlew --daemon

But when executing again my batch file I still got the same error message. The only way I was able to make it work again was rebooting my container. Heavy handed but it worked. I would like to know a better way!.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Gradle sync failed: Timeout waiting to lock daemon addresses registry [...].
It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

Owner PID: 4567
Our PID: 5678
Owner Operation: ...

My solution was to delete .gradle caches folder (In Mac you can use Command + Shift + . to get .gradle folder)

/user/..../.gradle/caches

Everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, i run the following command and it worked for me,

> find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to downgrade the gradle version from 6.8.2 to 6.7.2

Comment: Perfect, it´s a permanent solution....Well, It's not a perfect solution, but it works for now

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but nothing worked .
Restarting my macbook solved the issue .

So , in case above solutions are not working try the old way i.e. restarting !!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was because I tried to start `gradlew` by WSL `bash` instead of by Cygwin's which resulted in an error:

```
> Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
   > java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
```

I have noticed a message:

```
The daemon log file: /mnt/c/srv/gradle/daemon/6.6.1/daemon-29382.out.log
```

For Cygwin that path should have been started with `/cygdrive/c`.