# When i run my flutter app in android studio i got the below error.How can i fix it

Tags: flutter, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Gradle could not start your build.

> Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\DELL.gradle\caches\journal-1\journal-1.lock (Access is denied)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Comment: Please post `flutter doctor` response.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, these actions worked for me: Close IDE. Go to windows task manager -> processes. Find java.exe processes there and end them.

Or try to these commands:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

OR

```
gradle --stop
```

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874147/15117215)